# Accessing container directly

Tags: docker-swarm

After having set up my swarm network with 3 hosts (manager1, worker1, worker2), I created an overlay network :

```
docker network create --driver=overlay testNet
```

Then created a service, based on couchbase (for example, any other image exposing a non stateless web ui is having same issue)

```
docker service create --name db --network=testNet --publish 8091:8091 couchbase
```

If I try to access the web ui located on port 8091, everything works fine, until I start scaling the service to 2 (or more).

```
docker service scale db=2
```

At this point, the swarm load balancer keeps redirecting the requests between the 2 containers, rendering the web ui unusable.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not personally recommend using Docker Swarm in conjunction with Couchbase Server as it does have an impedance mismatch. It would be more sensible to specifically create a Couchbase container on each server which requires it (and only one per server to avoid single points of failure!) and then to forward the appropriate ports on that server.

In spite of this, the answer in this case would be to access each node/container individually, you can do this by accessing the container via it's private IP. You can identify this IP by grabbing the container ID using `docker ps` and then looking for the IP in `docker inspect <container id>`.

Comment: the private IP of the container is not accessible outside of the swarm. what I did for the moment is to run a proxy container that forwards the request to the private IP.

Comment: regarding couchbase on swarm, I see your point, but how do I register my couchbase containers on the swarm DNS, in order to access them without  hard coding their IP adresses ?